# qgis-midvatten-plugin - preparing 3D-data for Qgis2threejs plugin

Tags: qgis, qgis2threejs, midvatten

I'm trying to do a simple task in a 64 bits windows OS - preparing 3D-data for Qgis2threejs plugin, but i have the following error message (https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin/wiki/7.-Utilities):

```
2019-03-10T22:31:25     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/Particular/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis-midvatten-plugin-master\midvatten.py", line 177, in 
              self.actionPrepareFor2Qgis2ThreeJS.triggered.connect(lambda x: self.prepare_layers_for_qgis2threejs())
              File "C:\Users\Particular\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qgis-midvatten-plugin-master\tools\midvatten_utils.py", line 1440, in new_func
              result = func(*args, **kwargs)
              File "C:/Users/Particular/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis-midvatten-plugin-master\midvatten.py", line 874, in prepare_layers_for_qgis2threejs
              PrepareForQgis2Threejs(qgis.utils.iface, self.ms.settingsdict)
              File "C:\Users\Particular\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qgis-midvatten-plugin-master\tools\prepareforqgis2threejs.py", line 48, in __init__
              newkey = 'strat_' + utils.return_lower_ascii_string(key)
              File "C:\Users\Particular\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\qgis-midvatten-plugin-master\tools\midvatten_utils.py", line 439, in return_lower_ascii_string
              filtered_string = filtered_string.lower()
             AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug that is now fixed.

Download latest master branch from https://github.com/jkall/qgis-midvatten-plugin and it should work!

Thanks for finding the bug!

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! Now it is working.